# TeXShop Paste Spreadsheet Cells macro does not work with special characters

Tags: errors, editors, texshop, mac

Texshop (3.61) menu: Macros -> Paste Spreadsheet Cells does not work when the original Excel spreadsheet has special characters and diacritics.

This is the code I use in the beginning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
```

The error message is:

[image: screenshot]

Any help available on this?

Comment: have you specified to latex that you are using non ascii characters, eg `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` ? what does "does not work" mean? (get error (what error message?) or get no output, or get wrong output...

Comment: as @DavidCarlisle points out, you don't really give us much to go on here. However, one suggestion (in the absence of any substantive data) is to include `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`,  to support  non-ascii characters?

Comment: so it is not a tex error at all but in some applescript program. Since the error message seems to suggest that it only supports ASCII that is presumably just the way it is and none ASCII characters don't work. But I don't have a Mac so have no idea about this or any other applescript program.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can usually copy/paste text with diacritics from Excel into Texshop without any problems, although occasionally some characters are represented as ? For example, à works but not  ą . The error originates somewhere else and we wait with baited breath for more info from the OP.

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson probably related that à is U+00E0 so fits in one byte in legacy encodings such as latin1 but ą is U+0105 so above FF and so most likely requires a multi-byte encoding such as utf-8.

Comment: Hi I'm the author of this script (which is a Ruby script with an AppleScript wrapper) and I'm aware of the bug. Hopefully it can be solved.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an updated version of the Applescript that should solve the problem. Open the Macro Editor in TeXShop and click on the Paste Spreadsheet Cells macro.

Replace the existing macro with the following, and save it.

```
--Applescript direct
--This script copyright 2009,2010,2016 by Alan Munn <amunn@msu.edu>
--Version 1.2 2016/05/11
--Copy cells from Excel or other spreadsheet program and
-- use this script to paste the cells into your LaTeX source
-- in a variety of different table styles.
set mainList to {"cells","booktabs", "simple","longtable" }
choose from list mainList with prompt "Choose a table format"
if the result is not false then
    set tablestyle to result as text
    do shell script  "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;
                     export LANG=en_US.UTF-8;
                                ~/Library/TeXShop/bin/csv2latex" & " " &  tablestyle
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using {command down}
end if
--End of Applescript
```

The new version of the macro will be included in the next version of TeXShop, so this is essentially a temporary fix.